# How can I get Twilio conference call length when both callers are connected?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to get conference call length from the moment when both callers are actually connected. **Is it possible at all?**

I know that for call recording it is possible to specify `trim` attribute as `trim-silence` and it will record the call from the moment when callers are connected. Is there any way to do the same with conference call length?

Comment: Can't you just get the time when the conference call ends and subtract the time when the last participant joins the call?

Comment: Yes, I've thought about that, but I also thought maybe there exist more straightforward way to do this. One more thing is that when the last participant joins the call, he can hear welcome message and after that will be connected with another participant, so it would be necessary to know the duration of that welcome message and also subtract it from the call length. Anyway thank you for response!